# ionic 3 with JWT Authentication login Error

Tags: authentication, ionic3, lexikjwtauthbundle

I built an API with symfony, and all is working fine in the browser, but when I try on my device (Android) I get an error 'Server error', is it a problem of compatibility I post my code, please Help!

Login in provider :

```
    login(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let body = "_username=" + credentials._username + "&_password=" + credentials._password;
    return this.http.post(this.cfg.apiUrl + this.cfg.user.login, body, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
          let rs = data.json();
         this.saveData(data);
         this.idToken = rs.token;
         this.scheduleRefresh();
      })
      .catch((err: any) => this.handleError(err));
}
```

Function handleError :

```
protected handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Package json :

```
{
  "name": "maquinas",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Auth Provider:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {UserModel} from '../models/user.model';
import {CredentialsModel} from '../models/credentials.model';
import {AuthHttp, JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import *  as AppConfig from '../app/config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private cfg: any;
  idToken: string;
  refreshSubscription: any;


  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private http: Http,
    private jwtHelper:JwtHelper,
    private authHttp: AuthHttp) {

    this.cfg = AppConfig.cfg;
    this.storage.get('id_token').then(token => {
        this.idToken = token;
    });

  }

  register(userData: UserModel) {
    return this.http.post(this.cfg.apiUrl + this.cfg.user.register, userData)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.saveData(data)
        let rs = data.json();
        this.idToken = rs.token;
        this.scheduleRefresh();
      })
      .catch(e => console.log("reg error", e));


  }



  login(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let body = "_username=" + credentials._username + "&_password=" + credentials._password;
    return this.http.post(this.cfg.apiUrl + this.cfg.user.login, body, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
          let rs = data.json();
         this.saveData(data);
         this.idToken = rs.token;
         this.scheduleRefresh();
      })
      .catch((err: any) => this.handleError(err));


  }
  protected handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  saveData(data: any) {

    let rs = data.json();

    this.storage.set("user", rs.user);
    this.storage.set("id_token", rs.token);
  }

  logout() {
    // stop function of auto refesh
    this.unscheduleRefresh();
    this.storage.remove('user');
    this.storage.remove('id_token');

  }

  isValid() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }


  public getNewJwt() {
     // Get a new JWT from Auth0 using the refresh token saved
     // in local storage
    this.storage.get("id_token").then((thetoken)=>{

      let  senddata: { Token:string} = {
           Token : thetoken
        };

        this.http.get(this.cfg.apiUrl + this.cfg.user.refresh+"?Token="+thetoken)
         .map(res => res.json())
         .subscribe(res => {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
           console.log(res.status);
           // If the API returned a successful response, mark the user as logged in
           // this need to be fixed on Laravel project to retun the New Token ;
            if(res.status == 'success') {
                   this.storage.set("id_token", res.token);

             } else {
               console.log("The Token Black Listed");
               this.logout();

            }
         }, err => {
           console.error('ERROR', err);
          });

       });

   }


  public scheduleRefresh() {
  // If the user is authenticated, use the token stream
  // provided by angular2-jwt and flatMap the token
  let source = Observable.of(this.idToken).flatMap(
    token => {
      // The delay to generate in this case is the difference
      // between the expiry time and the issued at time
      let jwtIat = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token).iat;
      let jwtExp = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token).exp;
      let iat = new Date(0);
      let exp = new Date(0);

      let delay = (exp.setUTCSeconds(jwtExp) - iat.setUTCSeconds(jwtIat));
      console.log("will start refresh after :",(delay/1000)/60);
      if(delay-1000<=0)
      delay = 1;
      return Observable.interval(delay);
    });

  this.refreshSubscription = source.subscribe(() => {
    this.getNewJwt();
  });
}



public startupTokenRefresh() {
    // If the user is authenticated, use the token stream
    // provided by angular2-jwt and flatMap the token
    this.storage.get("id_token").then((thetoken)=>{

      if(thetoken){

        let source = Observable.of(thetoken).flatMap(
          token => {
            // Get the expiry time to generate
            // a delay in milliseconds
            let now: number = new Date().valueOf();
            let jwtExp: number = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token).exp;
            let exp: Date = new Date(0);
            exp.setUTCSeconds(jwtExp);
            let delay: number = exp.valueOf() - now;

            if(delay <= 0) {
              delay=1;
            }
             // Use the delay in a timer to
            // run the refresh at the proper time
            return Observable.timer(delay);
          });

         // Once the delay time from above is
         // reached, get a new JWT and schedule
         // additional refreshes
         source.subscribe(() => {
           this.getNewJwt();
           this.scheduleRefresh();
         });

      }else{
        //there is no user logined
        console.info("there is no user logined ");

      }

    });


    }




public unscheduleRefresh() {
// Unsubscribe fromt the refresh
if (this.refreshSubscription) {
this.refreshSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
}

}
```

In the browser works fine, but in android no, please some help!

Comment: which version of Angular are you using? 5.0 or pre? Specifically which http module you are leveraging? please share FULL code of the component and service

Comment: Can you please mention the value of err object you are getting in handleError method ?

Comment: Sergey Rudenko : I updated it, you will see the code of package.json and my user provider too.
Yuvraj Patil : The problem is that i can't see any error, it says 'Server error' no more.

If you have a link of any authentication provider that works on browser and devices, it will help too much, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `let rs = data.json();`

With `let rs = data.text()();`